# Configure maven-deploy-plugin when mvn release

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am quite new in maven so it might be a silly question.

I am running the mvn release:

```
mvn clean release:prepare release:perform
```

In the log I can see:

```
[INFO] [DEBUG] Configuring mojo '...maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy' with basic configurator -->

             ...
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
```

**I would like to override skip properties** so I added into my pom:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
        <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But it seems that it doesn't have any effect. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Why would you like to skip the deploy plugin? Cause it's responsible to transfer the created artifacts into the repository.... ?

Comment: I actually don't care about setting this property but more general how-to override any property settings.

Comment: Can you explain what kind of problem you have?

Comment: Sure, when I execute "mvn clean release:prepare release:perform" the maven-deploy-plugin is executed, I wonder how can I configure this plugin.

Comment: It would be better if you asked for the concrete problem with the deploy plugin that you want solve, rather than creating a question with a property that you are not interested in.

Comment: You are repeating . the information which is already given in the question but not answered the question I have asked...does not really help...